# Como voltar ao "estado normal" do Html após uma consulta Javascript sem refresh?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

tudo bem?
estou com uma dúvida bem chata aqui e não consegui achar nenhuma solução viável.
Bem, vou explicar o problema.

Essa é minha classe onde eu retornarei minha consulta

```
<div class="col-lg-2 result"> 
    ...  AQUI DENTRO ESTARÁ A CONSULTA INICIAL DA PAGINA
</div>
```

e esse é meu código para fazer com que cada letra que eu digite me retorne a consulta

```
$(function(){
//Pesquisar os cursos sem refresh na página
$("#pesquisa").keyup(function(){

    var pesquisa = $(this).val();

    //Verificar se há algo digitado
    if(pesquisa != ''){
        var dados = {
            palavra : pesquisa
        }       
        $.post('busca.php', dados, function(retorna){
            $(".result").html(retorna);
        });
    }else{
        $('.result').load('');
    }       
});
});
```

Agora o problema, quando eu faço a pesquisa ela subscreve a div ( isso eu quero que aconteça), porém ao apagar todas as letras digitadas, eu preciso que a div volte ao estado original, ou seja, o estado em que apenas a minha consulta php age sobre o código.

Alguém teria uma dica de como resolver isso?

Comment: Você já tentou usar o 'AutoComplete' do Jquery ?

Comment: Porque é que o php não retorna esse html no caso da busca ser vazia?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210711/combobox-ajax-php-nao-retorna-nada?noredirect=1#comment430860_210711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta vc guardar os dados da `div.result` antes da primeira interação. Veja a variável `htmlOrig`. Quando não tiver mais nada pra mostrar, volte com eles pro lugar anterior e seu HTML volta ao estado original.

```js
$(function(){

var htmlOrig = $('.result').html();

//Pesquisar os cursos sem refresh na página
$("#pesquisa").keyup(function(){

    var pesquisa = $(this).val();

    //Verificar se há algo digitado
    if(pesquisa != ''){
        var dados = {
            palavra : pesquisa
        }       
        $.post('busca.php', dados, function(retorna){
            $(".result").html(retorna);
        });
    }else{
        $('.result').html(htmlOrig);
    }       
});
});
```

Comment: Certo Ricardo, irei estudar esse método. 
E me diga, essa é uma boa solução/prática pra resolver esse problema?

Comment: é uma solução. Se resolve o seu caso aí depende do que tem dentro da div.result, principalmente.

Comment: Certo, vou ver se resolveu, caso não tenha resolvido eu volto aqui com mais detalhes